# Express redirect sending page as data to success of angular $http instead of redirecting to the page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

When the user is validated the client get the page contents of `home.html` in `result` instead of redirecting to the `home.html`.

Client side call:

```
$http({
method: "post",
url: "http://localhost:2222/validateUser",
data: {
    username: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password
}

}).then(function (result) {
    if (result.data && result.data.length) {
        alert('User validated');
    } else {
        alert('invalid user');
    }
});
```

Server side controller method:

```
module.exports.validateUser = function (req, res) {
  User.find({ 'username': req.body.username, 'password': req.body.password }, function (err, result) {
    if (result.length) {
        req.session.user = result[0]._doc;
        res.redirect('/home');
    }else{
        res.json(result);
    }
  });
};
```

Route in app.js:

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    var path = require('path');
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('server/views/home.html'));
});
```

Comment: try this: res.redirect(path.resolve('server/views/home.html'));

Comment: You can't do a browser redirect from AJAX. You need to check if it should be redirected and do it on the client.

Comment: Is it really a good practise to move the redirection logic on client, and isn't there a workaround for same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your redirect logic to the client.

Client:

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:2222/validateUser",
    data: {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
    },
}).then(function (result) {
    alert('user validated');
    window.location.replace('/home');
}).catch(function(result) {
    alert('login failed');
});
```

Server:

```
module.exports.validateUser = function (req, res) {
  User.find({ 'username': req.body.username, 'password': req.body.password }, function (err, result) {
    if (result.length) {
        req.session.user = result[0]._doc;
        res.send('OK');
    } else {
        // responding with a non-20x or 30x response code will cause the promise to fail on the client.
        res.status(401).json(result);
    }
  });
};
```